# PostSharp aspect build error on class derived from generic type

Tags: c#, generics, postsharp

I am trying to use the Dispatched aspect on a class to push execution to the UI thread but I am getting an error at build time.  Here is the error:

> You cannot add an aspect to a generic type instance. Add the aspect to the corresponding generic type definition.

It seems to have a problem with me putting the aspect on a class that derives from a generic type.

Here is a simplified code sample that can reproduce this:

```
interface IView
{
}

class Presenter<T>
{
}

class DataPresenter : Presenter<IView>
{
    [Dispatched]
    void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is it not possible to use aspects on a class that inherits from generic types?

Comment: This is a bug of [Dispatched] attribute that is trying to introduce a service aspect to the base class. We will let you know as soon as it is fixed. As a workaround, please declare non-generic base class for `Presenter<T>` or move `Presenter<T>` to another assembly. Thanks!

Comment: I found a work around to the problem, I will add my answer below.

Comment: Update: The related bug has been fixed in PostSharp 4.3.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel mentions in the comments, this is a bug in PostSharp but I found a work around.  I modified the presenter class:

```
class Presenter<T> : DispatcherObject, IDispatcherObject
{
    IDispatcher IDispatcherObject.Dispatcher => DispatcherFactory.GetDispatcherForWindowsDispatcher(Dispatcher);
}
```

In my code Presenter was already inheriting from DispatcherObject, so implementing the IDispatcherObject interface fixed my issue.

Comment: Update: The related bug has been fixed in PostSharp 4.3.24.